# Change value of a TextFormField by another TextFormField

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to change the value of second TextFormField, when user inputs the first TextFormField.

```
TextEditingController txt1  = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController txt2  = TextEditingController();

  new Container(
    child: new TextFormField(
      controller: txt1,
      autovalidate: true,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      validator: (value){
        if(value.isEmpty){
          txt2.text = "0";
          return 'Please enter value';
        }else{
          txt2.text = ((10/100)*value).toString();
        }
      },
    )
  ),
  new Container(
    child: new TextFormField(
      controller: txt2,
      enabled: false
    )
  ),
```

It is working correctly. But in the run console I see the following error message

> "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested way will be to use `listener` - but another short way in your code is to use future.

Working code of what you have:

```
child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Expanded(
              child: new TextFormField(
            controller: txt1,
            autovalidate: true,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                Future.value(Duration(seconds: 1)).whenComplete(() {   // Add this
                  txt2.text = "0";
                });
                return 'Please enter value';
              } else {
                Future.value(Duration(seconds: 1)).whenComplete(() {  //Add this
                  txt2.text = ((10 / 100) * int.parse(value)).toString();
                });
                return null;
              }
            },
          )),
          Expanded(child: TextFormField(controller: txt2, enabled: false)),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working now without any error. Anyhow, Ill change my code and use listener as you suggested. Thanks again.